# discord.js bot crashes after trying to send a message in a channel it can't send messages

Tags: node.js, crash, discord.js

Well discord.js bot crashes after trying to send a message in a channel it sees but can't send messages

well I get a crash after that, how can I fix this? here is the error it shows it shows for other commands too

```js
 /home/pi/Desktop/floppa_gaming/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/pi/Desktop/floppa_gaming/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/pi/Desktop/floppa_gaming/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (/home/pi/Desktop/floppa_gaming/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:171:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/785243249072930869/messages',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: 'You can use get help by saying "floppa help" in the chat :wink:',
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

and if anyobody wants to see my terrible code here it is

```js
 const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed, Permissions } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,] });


var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('./floppa/');



client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setStatus('invisible') //You can set idle, dnd or invisible
  client.user.setActivity("use floppa to get a image!",  { type: 'PLAYING' }) // PLAYING , LISTENING , WATCHING , STREAMING
  console.log("on discord lol");
});



 const { AutoPoster } = require('topgg-autoposter')

 const poster = AutoPoster('token', client) // tells topgg amount of servers ur bot is in 

 // optional
 poster.on('posted', (stats) => { // ran when succesfully posted
  console.log(`Posted stats to Top.gg | ${stats.serverCount} servers`)
})


 client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'floppa') 
    {
        imageNumber = files[Math.floor(Math.random()*files.length)]
        msg.channel.send ( {files: ["./floppa/" + imageNumber]} )
    }
        
// finds a random image in a folder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shown is: `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`

This means that your bot does not have permission to send messages in that channel. To avoid your bot crashing when this happens, you need to do one of the following:

- Catch the error:

  ```js
  msg.channel.send("stuff").catch((err) => {/* handle errors */});
  ```
- Verify that your bot has the permissions to post before posting:

  ```js
  if (msg.guild && msg.channel.permissionsFor(msg.guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"))) {
    msg.channel.send("stuff");
  }
  ```